# Multiply by decimal by number of decimal places

Tags: floating-point, decimal-point

I need a way to multiple the a float by the number of decimal places.

e.g.

```
Number = 10.04
Number of Decimal Places = 2
Result = 1004

Number = 123.421
Number of Decimal Places = 3
Result = 123421
```

so on and so forth, I have a method written to return the number of decimal places, but how can I expected result as mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just moving the decimal point?
If so... #EDITTED#
result = number * (10 to the power of decimal places)

Comment: How will this work? if the numberOfDecimal=3, then 3*10 makes it 30 and 30*number, is a different value!!

Comment: Rushed it, sorry (I'm very hungover). meant to be to ten to the power of decimal places. You need an extra zero for each position that the decimal point needs to be moved.

Answer (score 3):

A `float` value does not *have* decimal places. So if you want to do anything that involves decimal places, you have to stop using `float`. Otherwise, you'll inevitably get unexpected (wrong) results.

Read the [Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Got another way:

Float.toString(10.234f).replace(".", "")

returns 10234!!